# NSFont autoscaling via NSStringDrawingContext does not work

Tags: swift, nsattributedstring, appkit, core-text

I'm building a small test app that draws text into rectangles on images. Said text might sometimes be too long to be drawn into said rectangles, but I thought I would simply use `NSStringDrawingContext` and `NSAttributedString.boundingRect(with:options:context:)` in order to generate a scale factor that I'd use to scale the font down to make it fit.

The problem I'm now facing is that this straight up is not working, as `actualScaleFactor` is always 1.0, even though it should be less than that. To demonstrate, I've prepared a minimal reproducible example.

The image used as input variable `image` can be found here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/19UvI.png. The text target rectangle `rect` is marked by the black rectangle in the image.

```swift
let paragraphStyle = NSMutableParagraphStyle()
paragraphStyle.alignment = .left
paragraphStyle.lineBreakMode = .byWordWrapping

let textAttributes: [NSAttributedString.Key: Any] = [
    .font: NSFont(name: "Futura-Bold", size: 100)!,
    .foregroundColor: NSColor.white,
    .paragraphStyle: paragraphStyle,
]
let text = "A very long string that'll be auto-wrapped when it gets drawn"
let attrStr = NSAttributedString(string: text, attributes: textAttributes)

let drawingOptions: NSString.DrawingOptions = [.usesLineFragmentOrigin, .usesFontLeading]
let context = NSStringDrawingContext()

// counter-intuitively, 1.0 is the "maximum" minimum scale factor
// see also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/nsstringdrawingcontext/1534020-minimumscalefactor
context.minimumScaleFactor = 1.0 

let position = NSPoint(x: 80, y: 140)
let size = NSSize(width: 640, height: 200)
let rect = NSRect(origin: position, size: size)

let newImage = NSImage(size: image.size, flipped: true) { imageRect in
    image.draw(in: imageRect)

    // let NSStringDrawingContext do its thing
    attrStr.boundingRect(with: size, options: drawingOptions, context: context)
    print("Actual Scale Factor: \(context.actualScaleFactor)") // is always 1.0

    attrStr.setAttributes([.font: font.withSize(font.pointSize * context.actualScaleFactor)], range: NSRangeFromString(text))
    attrStr.draw(with: rect, options: drawingOptions, context: context)

    return true
}
```

At this point, `newImage` should be an image that looks something like this:

[image: successful font shrinkage]
(recreated in an image editing tool)

Instead, this is what I get:
[image: no font shrinkage at all]

This is obviously wrong.

While I was looking for a solution, I found [this related SO question from 2013](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17633032/how-to-make-nsstringdrawingcontext-shrink-text) with a conclusion of "it's broken", but surely this has to be possible *somehow* by now. iOS and macOS label controls both have this feature, SwiftUI even makes it available as a modifier entitled simply `minimumScaleFactor`. Is there a replacement API I'm not aware of?

Comment: Did you find out the solution?